# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR - extract only matched string

Tags: regex, oracle

For e.g. `one > two > three > four > five`

word `four` should be the resulting string.

I have this expression for matching the desired output: `(?<=^(\w+\s>\s){3})(\w+)`.

But it returns the empty string using this:
`REGEXP_SUBSTR (t.column, '(?<=^(\w+\s>\s){3})(\w+)')`.

What is wrong here?
Thank you.

**Note**: strings separated by '>' sign can be composed of two or more words. For example:
`one > two > three > four1 four2 > five` should return `four1 four2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be a regular expression solution, use `substr` + `instr` combination (`result_1`).

Or, if it has to be regexp, and if string really looks as you posted it, fetch 4th *word* from it (`result_2`).

```
select trim(substr(col, instr(col, '>', 1, 3) + 1,
                        instr(col, '>', 1, 4) - instr(col, '>', 1, 3) - 1
                  )) result_1,
       --
       regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 4) result_2
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the non-consuming pattern into a consuming one, and use additional arguments to make sure the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns the right capture:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR (t.column, '^([^>]+\s+>\s+){3}\s*([^>]*[^[:space:]>])', 1, 1, NULL, 2)
```

Note there is no more lookbehind in the regex and since you need Group 2 value, the last argument is set to `2`.

See an [Oracle DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5866a1d4b2fbe611c57926ec5a119b99):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    'one > two > three > four or more > five',
    '^([^>]+\s+>\s+){3}\s*([^>]*[^[:space:]>])',
    1, 1, NULL, 2) as Result from dual
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Please take a look at the edited question: Note: strings separated by '>' sign can be composed of two or more words. For example: one > two > three > four1 four2 > five should return four1 four2 –

Comment: @BitWise I updated the solution with negated bracket expressions.